# brew is not found when I sshpass to the server

Tags: bash, bashrc, sshpass, bash-profile, brew

brew is installed on the server but when I sshpass to the server, it throws `bash: brew: command not found` and same is happening for ideviceinstaller `bash: ideviceinstaller: command not found`

This is the command I'm using

```
sshpass -p password ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no user@**** 'cd /Users/user/Documents/workspace/iOS; brew'
```

```
sshpass -p password ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no user@**** 'cd /Users/user/Documents/workspace/iOS; ideviceinstaller -l'
```

I have exactly same .bashrc and .bash_profile.

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk

export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -o KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'

export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

.profile

```
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Not sure what mistake I'm making. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You're getting bitten by the combination of `ssh` and the notoriously unintuitive way the `bash` shell chooses the login scripts it executes.

From the `ssh(1)` man page (emphasis mine):

> When the user's identity has been accepted by the server, the server either **executes the given command in a non-interactive session** or, if no command has been specified, logs into the machine and gives the user a normal shell as an interactive session. [...]
>
> If an interactive session is requested ssh by default will only request a pseudo-terminal (pty) for interactive sessions when the client has one. [...]
>
> If no pseudo-terminal has been allocated, the session is transparent and can be used to reliably transfer binary data.

It does not explicitly say it, but when you specify a command to run at the remote end, `ssh` assumes that you are running a non-interactive session, and will not assign a pseudo-terminal (pty) at the remote end unless you use the `-t` option to `ssh`.

This turns out to be important for the shell at the remote end.

From the `bash(1)` man page:

> A **login shell** is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, or one started with the `--login` option.
>
> An **interactive shell** is one started without non-option arguments  (unless `-s` is specified) and without the `-c` option whose standard input and error are both connected to terminals (as determined by `isatty(3)`), or one started with the `-i` option. [...]

You've got no (pseudo-)terminal, and do have a command to run as a set of non-option arguments, so `bash` is getting started as a *non-interactive login shell*. So what scripts does it run in that situation?

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or **as a non-interactive shell with the --login option**, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

So, the `/etc/profile` and your `~/.bash_profile` may or may not be getting executed, depending on whether or not your shell gets an explicit `--login` option.

How about `~/.bashrc`?

> When an **interactive shell** that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and  executes commands from /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if these files exist.

So `~/.bashrc` is only for interactive shells and will be skipped, as will be `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

> When bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for example, it  looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment, expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute. Bash behaves as if the following command were executed:
>
> ```
>          `if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi`
> ```
>
> but the value of the PATH variable is not used to search for the filename.

So unless `$BASH_ENV` is set (by either `sshd` or the system default environment), which would be unusual, then it is possible that **no login script will be executed at all** in the case of a non-interactive login.

As a result, your PATH may be drastically shorter than usual when you're running non-interactive commands. You can verify this yourself this way:

```
local$ ssh remote
remote$ printenv PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/Users/<username>/perl5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
remote$ exit
local$ ssh remote printenv PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

This example was created using macOS 10.14.6 as the remote host. Note that in particular `/usr/local/bin` is missing from the PATH on a non-interactive session.

As a workaround, you may have to explicitly source one or more of the normal login script(s). Example:

```
local$ ssh remote "source /etc/profile; printenv PATH"
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Note that the PATH is better but still not quite the same as in the interactive login, and sourcing `~/.bashrc` does not help. This turns out to be because my `~/.bashrc` has this at the very beginning:

```
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
    return
fi
```

On non-interactive shells, "$PS1" will not be set. So this test causes the entire `~/.bashrc` to be skipped on non-interactive sessions.

Anything in login scripts that generates output **should** be encapsulated by such tests, or else things that pipe stuff through a SSH session, such as `scp`, `rsync` or `git pull` may fail encountering unexpected script output instead of the application protocol data they're waiting for.